# Moduli of smooth complex curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

The space $\mathcal{M}_g$ is the moduli space of a curve $C$. I see that we can define the moduli space of spin curves $S_g$ as the set of $C,L$ with $L$ a theta characteristic of $C$.
Can you suggest some references about that space or lectures?